# How do I create a thank you page for a form with a summary of user submitted data and a PayPal Button? (Wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, plugins

I'm running the latest version of Wordpress (3.1.2) and need to create a form that, when submitted, will produce a Thank You page with my own text, a summary of the data that the user submitted, as well as a PayPal button. I'm not a programmer (although I do know HTML), so I've installed the Custom Contact Forms Wordpress plugin, and it looks very user friendly, but I'm not sure how to create what I just described. It allows you to create a custom Thank You Page with HTML, but you have to follow certain parameters.

Would appreciate step-by-step instructions on how to do this. I just need instructions for the basic template of it. I can fill in the specific code after I have that.

If another Wordpress plugin is better for this, please mention which one and how I would set up the Thank You page I just described.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off with a plugin. Creating a form from scratch can be done, but it's pretty intensive coding you're talking about here. (I could put in a ton of code here, but when I say a ton, I mean it. If you're not very well-versed in PHP, then it'll give you a headache.)  Gravity Forms is the best form plugin out there (and has Paypal integration with a click), but it's not free. Dagon Design's Form Mailer and cFormsII are both good plugins (and free), but you'll have to do some tweaking to get them to do what you want. Not as much as you'd be doing if you tried to create your own form, but a bit is needed.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I've used cForms II, but it's a bit cumbersome to set up.  How is Dagon Design's Form Mailer?  Is it easy to set up?  Is it just as good, if not better than cFormsII?  If so, could you give me some guidance as to how I would set it up for what I want it to do?  Also, have you heard of Formidable Pro?  Have you had any experience with it or heard any feedback on it?  It's just like Gravity Forms except half the cost for the developer version, and you get free lifetime updates.

Comment: I've never heard to "Formidable", but I do use Gravity Forms a lot lately.  As for DDFm, I've used it a lot in the past.  it has excellent documentation on how to create and setup the forms, and even my ost "computer illiterate" clients have had no issues creating forms for themselves. I find it works very well for simple forms - it does handle checkboxes and dropdowns easily, but if you get into more complicated stuff (like multi-page forms, etc.) it gets a little trickier.